# Data not fetching properly in to asp.net application using oracle 12c

Tags: asp.net, oracle11g

My application was developed in ASP.net 4.0 and we are using oracle DB as backend system. Recently our database migrated from ORACLE11g to Oracle12c and oracle12c client has installed in my application server and uninstalled previous versions of oracle client. The moment Oracle12c client installed on server, application not working properly.

Problem is, In my database table there is field called MENU_ID and it has values like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 Through stored procedure am returning this value through out parameter and am getting it into asp.net page using

```
OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

by passing OutPut parameter.

In output parameter am getting half of the data only i.e 1,2,3,4.

Suppose i changed MENU_ID value in database to 1,2,3,4 then In output parameter am getting half of the data only i.e 1,2.

This problem we are facing after installation of oracle client12c only and before  installation of client 12c there is no issue.

Any suggestion would be greatly helpful for us.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, Oracle Client 11g will work with Oracle 12c database, so - if possible, revert the change you've made (i.e. uninstall Client 12c and install Client 11g again).